# Intel Core i7 4770 or Xeon E3-1240 V3

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, performance, xeon

I'm trying to decide wether to get a **Intel Core i7 4770** or a **Xeon E3-1240 V3** processor. Their specs are exactly the same, except that the i7 has integrated graphics, and the Xeon does not. The Xeon is cheaper.

My question is then: Will the integrated graphics (in the i7) matter to the overall performance when I am getting a seperate graphics gard (GTX 660) anyway?

**Links**

- [Intel processor comparison](http://ark.intel.com/compare/75122,75055)
- [Benchmark comparison](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html)

Thanks!

Comment: One is a Haswell and the Xeon is Sandy bridge there is no comparison the Haswell is better

Comment: The E3 models ending in 5 have integrated graphics, so a E3-1245 v3 is closer spec wise to the i7 4770. The E3's have slightly higher clock speeds, some drivers for professional software and support ECC memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: NO. It doesn't matter.

And:
I was thinking about the exact same thing(i7 vs Xeon), two or three weeks ago.

I would recommend you to buy the i7. Why? Because you will still be able to use your computer, if your graphics-card(GTX660) will stop working. The i7 maybe costs a bit more, but in my opinion, the integrated Graphics-card is worth the money.